# Changes to the remote not seen by "git status" in local repo

Tags: git

I am facing something I do not understand.
I push and pull to a GitHub repository from two different machines.

When I commit a change locally from one of the machines and then push on the remote, on my other machine the repository does not see the change:

`git status` returns

> Your branch is up to date with origin master

Despite this, when I do `git pull` the change is applied to my local repository.

Moreover, making a commit directly on GitHub is not seen in either of the machines.

Thee command `git remote -v` returns the same thing on both systems.

I don't understand! Why can't I see that my local repository is behind the remote?

Comment: You should try `git fetch` instead: `git pull` will rebase/merge your branch. That's probably why you don't see anything in the status: your development on Windows and Linux does not differ that much for a merge conflict to occurs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You just need clarification about what `git status` actually means. `git status` doesn't go check the remote branch for changes. All it does is check what it *already knows* about the remote. You can use the command, `git remote update` to **fetch those changes** and then Git's "knowledge" of the remote branch will be updated. Running `git status` after that will do what you expected it to do in the first place.